# MSTest Command Line Options - Test Duration

Tags: command-line, mstest, performance-testing

I am trying to run MSTEST Performance Tests from the command line and I would like to change the Test Duration and Test Iterations values.  I can not find any documentation on how to update the values and the only way I have come up with to update the value is updating the XML, which is not ideal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the command(s) that you're executing?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53c5e418-5570-4678-bccf-8b76e19c9a2a/mstestexe-option-for-setting-different-constant-load-pattern?forum=vstest